Where do the queries made to the view via linked server run?
Say SQL Server Svr1 has a linked server configured called Svr2. Assume there is a view on Svr2 that joins multiple tables from Svr2.
Is there a deterministic way to know where the join (inside the view) and filtering will execute? On Svr1 or Svr2?
Example 1:
select * 
from Svr2.db.tbl.viewname

Example 2:
select * 
from Svr2.db.tbl.viewname 
where col1 = 'test'

I understand that if a join is made, then the SQL Server engine may decide to bring the entire table from Svr2 to Svr1, and then filter and join it. But this question is about a simple SELECT and WHERE.

Not sure what you are asking here. Both servers are going to be involved. One is processing where to find the data and since that data is remote the other server will find the data. What problem are you trying to solve?

Trying to understand if filtering happens on Svr1 or Svr2

Just use EXECUTE () AT [LinkedServer] method to guarantee execution on the linked server. This method also has much better parameters handling.

I did try using Svr2.master.dbo.sp_executesql( ... ), seems to work OK.

I would be surprised if the remote server sent the entire table back to svr1 just to throw away some of the data. That would be a massive performance issue.

@SeanLange - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/database-engine/linked-servers/decreased-performance-linkedserver-views

Not the sp_executesql. Check it out here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/technet-wiki/36213.sql-server-execute-at-linkedserver

Depends on the server provider me thinks. Some can do pushdown to the server, some don't, sql server probably can. You can see the actual query on the remote server by checking the query plan

I was looking for a deterministic answer

@YitzhakKhabinsky Svr2.master.dbo.sp_executesql( ... ) is same as EXEC AT

@variable, it is not. sp_executesql is for dynamic SQL and has nothing to do with the Linked Servers. Again, please check the following documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/technet-wiki/36213.sql-server-execute-at-linkedserver

You need to check the query plan, this will tell you whether the linked query was pre-filtered.

And the answer might be different for where col1 = 'test' vs where col1 = @value vs where col1 in (select value from @SelectedValues). At some point, as complexity increases, Svr1 may have to do the filtering.

Use OPENQUERY or the other alternatives mentioned for more predicted behaviour, I mostly avoid the 4-parter. Why are you interesting in this? Are you learning SQL Server or do you have a concrete problem you're solving? Or is this J Mini?
